# Spring JPA Criteria API Query on OneToMany List Field

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, criteria-api

**I want to load all the CustomerRequests for a specific Customer with the JPA/Hibernate Criteria API.**

In specific: I want to load all the CustomerRequest for which a CustomerRequest2Customer entry with a specific customerId exists.

```
@Entity
public class CustomerRequest {
    @Id
    private int id;
    private int priority;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customerRequestId")
    private List<CustomerRequest2Customer> listCustomerRequestToCustomer; //  <- Query this field         
}

@Entity
public class CustomerRequest2Customer {
    @Id
    private int id;
    @ManyToOne
    private Customer customer; //  <- Query this field
    @ManyToOne
    private CustomerRequest customerRequest;
}

@Entity
public class Customer {
    @Id
    private int id; //  <- Query this field
    private String name;
}
```

How I currently query other fields:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<CustomerRequest> cq = 
cb.createQuery(CustomerRequest.class);
Root<CustomerRequest> root = cq.from(CustomerRequest.class);
cq.where(cb.equal(root.get("priority"), 1));
return entityManager.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? How does your query look like?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I added what my query currently looks like, but I tried noch much I do not really have an idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to join the entities like this:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<CustomerRequest> cq = cb.createQuery(CustomerRequest.class);

Root<CustomerRequest> root = cq.from(CustomerRequest.class);
Join<CustomerRequest, CustomerRequest2Customer> customerRequest2Customer = root.join("listCustomerRequestToCustomer");
Join<CustomerRequest2Customer, Customer> customer = customerRequest2Customer .join("customer");

cq.where(cb.equal(customer .get("id"), 1));

return entityManager.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
```